# Can't make remote connection from MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to connect from Windows 10 to Ubunutu 14.04. I'm using ssh.
The connection appears to get as far as logging on to the machine, but it doesn't connect to the database. I know I'm using the correct password. 
The error message is:

```
Failed to connect to MYSQL at localhost:3306 through SSH tunnel at username@xx.xx.xx.xx with user xxxx 
Unable to establish SSL connection
```

The Log shows:

```
12:27:02 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one 
12:27:06 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to xx.xx.xx.xx:22 
12:27:08 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: TunnelManager.wait_connection returned OK 
12:27:08 [INF][sshtunnel.py:set_keepalive:502]: SSH KeepAlive setting skipped. 
12:27:08 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: SSH tunnel connect executed OK
```

The user I'm connecting to was created like this:

```
mysql> create database fred 
mysql> CREATE USER 'fred'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxx'; 
mysql> CREATE USER 'fred'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'; 
mysql> grant all privileges on fred.* to 'fred'@'x'; 
mysql> grant all privileges on fred.* to 'fred@'%'
```

I can connect from a remote ubuntu machine like this;

```
mysql --user=fred --host=xx.xx.xx.xx --port=3306 -p
```

There's no mention of the connection in /var/log/mysql

/var/log/auth shows

```
Dec  7 14:03:46 www.example.com sshd[14474]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Dec  7 14:03:47 www.example.com sshd[14474]: Accepted publickey for root from xx.xx.xx.xx port 53591 ssh2: RSA ...
Dec  7 14:03:47 www.example.com sshd[14474]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
```

The ssh connection is to root, but I've tried it with a non-root user and it made no difference.

These are the details from the connection tab:

```
SSH Hostname: xx.xx.xx.xx
SSH Username root
SSH KeyFile: [dir]\.ssh\id_rsa
MySQL Hostname:localhost
MySQL Server Port: 3306
username: xxxx
```

Comment: Can you show us how you've configured the tunnel in your ssh? You should double-check that you've set up a tunnel from local port 3306 to remote port 3306.

Comment: I haven't set up anything other than the details in the MySQL Workbench connection page. I think it takes care of setting up the tunnel. The connection definitely seems to be being made to the server. It's what happens after that that appears to be the problem. I've edited the question to include the details that I have in the connection page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look carefully at the error message. It says the SSL connection could not be established. It doesn't say anyhting about SSH. So I guess MySQL Workbench is set to use SSL encryption for the connection, which the server does not support. You can change that in the connection settings:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the SSL Wizard (also available from this page) to generate SSL certificates for a proper SSL connection.

Good news: starting with server 5.7.9 SSL is enabled by default and the server and client software automatically set up the SSL details. MySQL Workbench of course works with that too.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem for you is to configure correctly your SSH server to work with keys rather than passwords. Once check in its config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config & changed from no to yes the param responsible for TCP forwarding, thus AllowTcpForwarding yes.

Comment: There was no entry in sshd_config for AllowTcpForwarding. I added it and restarted ssh, but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: I don't have AllowTcpForwarding option in sshd_config file. is there is something wrong ?